# Formatting a two-column index with subitems

Tags: two-column, indexing, subitem

I have two problems whilst formatting a two-column index with subitems:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[indentunit=15pt,justific=raggedright, columnsep=10pt, font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text.

\index{Donahue!Alice}
\index{Donahue!Barney}

\index{Jones!Alvin}
\index{Jones!Billy}
\index{Jones!Carter}
\index{Jones!Dennis}

\index{Smith!Alex}
\index{Smith!Brian}
\index{Smith!Carrie}
\index{Smith!Dewey}
\index{Smith!Eric}
\index{Smith!Frank}
\index{Smith!Gary}
\index{Smith!Huey}
\index{Smith!Irma}
\index{Smith!Joey}
\index{Smith!Kevin}

\index{Scullion!Alex}
\index{Scullion!Brian}
\index{Scullion!Carrie}

\index{White!Alice}
\index{White!Barney}

\idxlayout{columns=2, font=small, columnsep=20pt}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this MWE (1) the index-entry »Smith« is cut off from its sub-entries and (2) the space between the groups (entry + sub-entry) is uneven.

My two questions: Would it be possible to (1) fix the space between the item-groups and also (2) implement an algorithm that makes the entry stick together with at least one (or two, or three) sub-entries in the same column?

For the MWE this would result in the right column being a little shorter than the left one. »Alex, 1« would be pulled towards »Smith«. In my opinion a little better that what is the case now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\@idxitem` (which `\item` is let equal to inside `theindex`) to do some bookkeeping, namely to reset a counter that each subsequent `\subitem` would decrease.

Also `\subitem` adds a penalty when the value of the counter is positive, so a page/column break is prohibited.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[indentunit=15pt,justific=raggedright, columnsep=10pt, font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}

\makeindex

\makeatletter
\let\ori@idxitem\@idxitem
\def\@idxitem{\clear@penalties\ori@idxitem}
\def\clear@penalties{\subitem@count=3 }
\newcount\subitem@count
\def\subitem{%
  \advance\subitem@count -1
  \par
  \ifnum\subitem@count>0 \penalty10000 \fi
  \ori@idxitem\hspace*{\ila@subindent}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text.

\index{Donahue!Alice}
\index{Donahue!Barney}

\index{Jones!Alvin}
\index{Jones!Billy}
\index{Jones!Carter}
\index{Jones!Dennis}

\index{Smith!Alex}
\index{Smith!Brian}
\index{Smith!Carrie}
\index{Smith!Dewey}
\index{Smith!Eric}
\index{Smith!Frank}
\index{Smith!Gary}
\index{Smith!Huey}
\index{Smith!Irma}
\index{Smith!Joey}
\index{Smith!Kevin}

\index{Scullion!Alex}
\index{Scullion!Brian}
\index{Scullion!Carrie}

\index{White!Alice}
\index{White!Barney}

\idxlayout{columns=2, font=small, columnsep=20pt}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will keep two subitems together with the main entry. With

```
\def\clear@penalties{\subitem@count=2 }
```

you'd get just one subitem attached.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to extend this solution to `\subsubitem`s? The solution worked fine in two instances, but in another instance I ran into a problem where the index has three levels. I tried to redefine the commands in an analogous way and added a penalty, but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 3):

The vertical spacing is different because the blank space is only inserted when there is a new letter (according to this [documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/indexing/makeindex/paper/ind.pdf)). Since you dislike it, I am going to fix it anyways.

I tried to write the solution in LaTeX3, but somehow regular expressions do not work in Boolean expressions. For convenience, I am using Lua instead. That is to say, the following code only runs in LuaLaTeX. The idea is simple: read the `ind` file generated by `makeindex` and fine-tune it based on our purposes.

You may need to compile the document twice for it work properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[indentunit=15pt,justific=raggedright, columnsep=10pt, font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{luacode*}

local inspect = require"inspect"

function fine_tune_index()
    local index_filename = tex.jobname .. ".ind"
    local newindex_filename = tex.jobname .. "-new.ind"
    local attr = lfs.attributes(index_filename)
    if attr == nil then
        return
    end

    local index_lines = {}
    for line in io.lines(index_filename) do
        table.insert(index_lines, line)
    end
    
    local new_lines = {}
    local new_line_buffer = {}
    local line=nil
    local has_space=true
    local search_end = #index_lines - 1
    local item_count = 0
    
    function flush_line_buffer()
        if #new_line_buffer > 1 then
            table.insert(new_line_buffer, 1, [[\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}]])
            table.insert(new_line_buffer, 4, [[\end{minipage}]])
        end
        for _, item in ipairs(new_line_buffer) do
            table.insert(new_lines, item)
        end
        new_line_buffer = {}
    end
    
    for i=2,search_end do
        line = index_lines[i]
        if line:find("\\item") then
            item_count = item_count + 1
            flush_line_buffer()
            if not has_space then
                table.insert(new_lines, "\\indexspace")
            end
            has_space = false
            table.insert(new_line_buffer, line)
        elseif line:find("\\indexspace") then
            has_space=true
            flush_line_buffer()
            table.insert(new_lines, line)
        else
            table.insert(new_line_buffer, line)
        end
    end
    
    flush_line_buffer()
    table.insert(new_lines, 1, index_lines[1])
    table.insert(new_lines, index_lines[#index_lines])
    local out_text = table.concat(new_lines, "\n")
    local outfile = io.open(newindex_filename, "w")
    outfile:write(out_text)
    outfile:close()
end


\end{luacode*}

\AtEndDocument{
    \directlua{fine_tune_index()}
}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\index{Donahue!Alice}
\index{Donahue!Barney}

\index{Jones!Alvin}
\index{Jones!Billy}
\index{Jones!Carter}
\index{Jones!Dennis}

\index{Smith!Alex}
\index{Smith!Brian}
\index{Smith!Carrie}
\index{Smith!Dewey}
\index{Smith!Eric}
\index{Smith!Frank}
\index{Smith!Gary}
\index{Smith!Huey}
\index{Smith!Irma}
\index{Smith!Joey}
\index{Smith!Kevin}

\index{Scullion!Alex}
\index{Scullion!Brian}
\index{Scullion!Carrie}

\index{White!Alice}
\index{White!Barney}

\idxlayout{columns=2, font=small, columnsep=20pt}


\ExplSyntaxOn
% create a new int variable to bypass checks
\int_new:c {\jobname-new@idxfile}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\printindex[\jobname-new]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a LaTeX solution.

Unfortunately, the `idxlayout` package doesn't offer a lot of hooks to make this kind of modifications, so my changes are somewhat invasive and will break if you use different layout options.

If you run into problems, the following could be made a bit more generic.

You should put this code into the preamble, for instance after loading `idxlayout`. What it does is redefine the required internals from `idxlayout` to make the desired changes. I tried to be as minimally invasive as possible, but meh.

```
% Could put this into a separate package which loads idxlayout
\makeatletter
% no additional space before new letters
\let\indexspace\relax
% rescue original definition
\let\orig@idxitem\@idxitem
% we need to know if a subitem is the first after an item
\newif\ifafteritem

% \item should do what it originally does, plus add vertical space,
% plus set the flag for \subitem
\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{%
  \orig@idxitem
  \vspace{\ila@initsep}%
  \afteritemtrue
}

% \subitem should refer to original definition of \@idxitem (to avoid
% adding vertical space), plus add penalty if it's the first subitem.
\renewcommand{\subitem}{%
  \orig@idxitem
  \ifafteritem\nobreak\fi
  \hspace*{\ila@subindent}%
  \afteritemfalse
}%
\renewcommand{\subsubitem}{\orig@idxitem\hspace*{\ila@subsubindent}}%
\makeatother
```

Result:

[image: resulting index layout]